# Facing difficulty to understand Recursion?

Tags: c, recursion, logic

I faced a problem few days ago.
The problem is following..

```
int func(n){
  if(n < 4)
    return func(++n) + func(++n);
  return n;
}
```

I compile & run the program by calling `func(0)` and it results 35.

But i can't visualize the stack tree.

Can anyone describe the stack.

Comment: I *think* this is undefined behaviour due to sequencing.

Comment: Also, why don't just do a `printf` to show `n` at the beggining of each invocation? And maybe the return values, too. That would help you.

Comment: No - the `++n`'s don't invoke undefined behaviour here. What is _unspecified behaviour_ is, however, the order in which the `+` operands are evaluated. Since they are identical, it is fine.

Comment: @AlexanderGessler No, it's UB. The two `++n`s are completely unsequenced.

Comment: Why? The compiler must pick an order in which the `func(++n)` are evaluated. Once one `func` is entered, it acts as a sequence point, so `n` is definitely incremented before the other operand is evaluated. Enlighten me what's wrong about that thinking :-)

Comment: @AlexanderGessler The `func()` calls themselves are sequenced, but not the evaluation of their arguments.

Comment: Since the program in the question contains undefined behavior, perhaps it would be better to change it so that the actual behavior is sure to match any explanation given. I think that `int tmp = func(++n); return tmp + fun(++n);` would be a minor enough change to avoid asking a new question.

Comment: @T.C. You're right, I got that confused - thanks for lighting me up.

Comment: See may answer. The incremented value is never used, so replace `++` by `+1` and `+2`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So here it goes.

```
func(1) + func(2)

func(2) + func(3) + func(3) + func(4)


func(3) + func(4) + func(4) + func(5) + func(4) + func(5) + 4

func(4) + func(5) + 4 + 4 +5 +4 + 5 +4

4 + 5 + 4 + 4 +5 +4 + 5 +4
```

35

Answer (score 4):

The question covers two unrelated issues.

The code as written has undefined behaviour. It is unspecified as to whether the function is called with (n+1) and (n+2), or twice with (n+1) or (n+2) or something else entirely. The relevant section of the standard is: C11 n1570 S6.5/2: [EDIT]

> If a side effect on a scalar object is unsequenced relative to either a different side effect
>   on  the  same  scalar  object  or  a  value  computation  using  the  value  of  the  same  scalar
>   object,  the  behavior  is  undeﬁned. If  there  are  multiple  allowable  orderings  of  the
>   subexpressions of an expression, the behavior is undeﬁned if such an unsequenced side
>   effect occurs in any of the orderings.
>   84)

This is easily fixed by a minor change to the code, as follows.

```
int func(n){
  if(n < 4) {
    return func(n+1) + func(n+2);
  }
  return n;
}
```

The real question is how this all works. Clearly each function calls itself twice, or not at all and it can only ever return 4 or 5 from the lowest level. This is the structure of a binary tree. Write out the tree and label each value, and you will get a string of 4s and 5s. They add up to 35.

Comment: "has implementation-defined behaviour". No it doesn't. It has undefined behavior.

Comment: It has absolutely defined behaviour

Comment: @IVAAAN123 “If a side effect on a scalar object is unsequenced relative to either a different side effect on the same scalar object or a value computation using the value of the same scalar object, the behavior is **undefined**. If there are multiple allowable orderings of the subexpressions of an expression, the behavior is **undefined** if such an unsequenced side effect occurs in any of the orderings.” C11 6.5:2

Comment: @PascalCuoq: Thanks for that. Couldn't find the right bit. The C++ standard has similar wording. See edit. Definitely UB.

Comment: @PascalCuoq, in C# it's defined

Comment: @IVAAAN123 And so if this was a C# question your comment would have value, but things being what they are, it is just noise.

Comment: @PascalCuoq Initially this question had C# tag, so my comment is about C#. Now i see, tags were edited..

Comment: @IVAAAN123 No, I do not think that this question was tagged C# at any point in time: http://stackoverflow.com/posts/25377313/revisions

Comment: @PascalCuoq I view only C# thread questions. So how this question could appear there? :o

Comment: Maybe you looked at the main no-specific-tag page by accident. Guys, seriously though, get over it >.>

Answer (score 1):

fun(0)

```
Stack- fun(1)+fun(2)
--------------------
stack- fun(2)+fun(3)+fun(2)
stack- fun(3)+fun(4)+fun(3)+fun(2)
stack- fun(4)+fun(5)+fun(4)+fun(3)+fun(2)
stack- 4+fun(5)+fun(4)+fun(3)+fun(2)
stack- 4+5+fun(4)+fun(3)+fun(2)
stack- 9+fun(4)+fun(3)+fun(2)
```

and so on you will find the result as 35; Consider first as at the top of stack.

Answer (score 0):

The output may be different with different compilers and different machines. It is like asking the value of undefined automatic variable.

The reason for undefined behavior is, in this case the operator `+` doesn’t have standard defined order of evaluation for its operands. Either `func(++n)` or `func(n++)` may be executed first. This comes from the concept of sequence points in C.

Comment: But here, it is `func(++n) + func(++n)`.